# Order and complete a list and its sub-lists by names

Tags: r

For example, if I had a list named "mylist" (please run the following code to see an example of the initial structure):

```
list1 <- list(b = 2 , c = 3  , a=7)
list2 <- list(f="g" , d = "a", c = "b" , e="f")
list3 <- list(i=10 ,o="b", j=7 , m="a")
sublist1 <- list(list1, list2)
mylist <- list(sublist1, list3)
```

Is there a way to sort the list and sublists alphabetically, based on their names? (please run the following code to see an example of the desired output in the list named "mylist")

```
list1 <- list(a = 7  , b = 2   , c=3)
list2 <- list(c = "b", d = "a" , e="f", f="g")
list3 <- list(i=10 , j=7 , m="a",o="b")
sublist1 <- list(list1, list2)
mylist <- list(sublist1, list3)
```

I would eventually like to convert it into a dataframe like this:

```
mylist<-data.frame(t(c("7", "2", "3", "b", "a", "f", "g", "10", "7" ,"a", "b")))
names(mylist)<-c("a","b","c1","c2","d","e","f","i","j","m","o")
```

As a second question, is it possible to complete the lists and sub-lists so they have the same structure? It would look like this (empty cases filled with "." , please run the following code to see an example of the desired output in the list named "mylist"):

```
list1 <- list(a = 7, b = 2   , c=3     , d="."  , e=".", f="." )
list2 <- list(a=".", b = "." , c = "b" , d = "a", e="f", f="g" )
list3 <- list(i=".",j="."    , m="."   , o=".")
sublist1<-list(list1,list2)
sublist1<-list(sublist1,list3)


list4 <- list(a=".", b = "." , c=  "." , d="."  , e=".", f="." )
list5 <- list(a=".", b = "." , c = "." , d="."  , e=".", f="." )
list6 <- list(i=10 , j=7     , m="a"   , o="b")
sublist2<-list(list4,list5)
sublist2<-list(sublist2,list6)

mylist <- list(sublist1, sublist2)
```

I would eventually like to convert it into a dataframe like this:

```
firstrow<-(c("7", "2", "3", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "b" ,"a", "f", "g", ". ", ".", ".", "."))
secondrow<-(c(".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "." ,".", ".", ".", "10", "7", "a", "b"))
mylist<-t(data.frame(firstrow, secondrow))
colnames(mylist)<-c("a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1","a2","b2","c2","d2","e2","f2","i","j","m","o")
rownames(mylist)<-c("1","2")
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Hack-R ! Thanks for your message, I edited the post.

Comment: Why would you want to order it? You can still work with it without necessarily being ordered

Comment: Hi Onyambu! Thanks for your message, I want to order the lists and in a following step convert them into a single data frame or export them to a csv.

Comment: what should your final dataframe look like?

Comment: The columns would be   "a, b, c1, c2, d, e, f, i , j m o". Edit: the second group of code I put represents an example where I would like all the information of a list placed as a single row. The third group of coding I put represents an example where I would like to see each sublist as a single row of the data frame, in the case of the third group of coding the columns would be  "a1 ,b1, c1, d1 ,e1, f1, a2 ,b2 ,c2 ,d2 ,e2 ,f2 , i, j m, o", apologies for the constant editing. I am afraid my explanation is not very clear, thanks for the help!

Comment: can you just include the final  dataframe?

Comment: Hi Onyambu! I updated the post with the data frame for both questions. Once again thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the list by name with basic R code and apply that to each sublist. You may unnest that list to a dataframe first.

```
list1 <- list(b = 2 , c = 3  , a=7)

list1[order(names(list1))]
#> $a
#> [1] 7
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] 3
```